# How can I have selectable labels?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to have label like controls which display certain information which can be selected. Which control to use?

I need the label (ie control) to be selectable.

The form may have several such controls and the information displayed in each is determined by a single drop down selection in the form.

Comment: ASP.NET, Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: So the text in the "label" needs to be selectable? How about disguising a TextBox to have no border and a background color that matches the background color of the form?

Answer (score 11):

What about a TextBox with `ReadOnly = true`?

That way the text is selectable and copiable, but the control cannot be edited.

By changing the `BorderStyle` to `None` you get the same visual appearance as a label.

Comment: Interesting post on how to make it auto-sized here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29101625/945456