# Native selectable auto-sized label in Windows Forms

Tags: .net, winforms

Is there a selectable (meaning I can copy text from label), auto-sizable label in the native windows forms controls?

Note that transparent a TextBox serves well for selectability, but not for the auto-size part.

Comment: What are your expectations on the auto-size part?

Comment: That it changes its size automatically to make the whole text visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to measure yourself, and add a little buffer to make it less jittery:

```
textBox1.MinimumSize = new Size(16, textBox1.Height);
textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;

void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int textWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font, Size.Empty,
                                           TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl).Width;
  textBox1.Width = textWidth + 8;
}
```

As far as labels are concerned, they simply draw text, so there isn't any selectable functionality like you get with a TextBox control.